# Visualizing choices of a cohort

Tags: visualization, data-visualization

Not sure how best to phrase it so it's easier to show. I have a table like this:

[image]

Where people choose a colour then choose to stick with that colour or switch to another. There is a third choice (same options) as well.

How can I show which 'paths' people took i.e. Show choice 1, then choice 2 for each choice 1 on the same graph?

What is the best program to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Parallel Sets](http://kosara.net/papers/2010/Kosara_BeautifulVis_2010.pdf) for this sort of approach.  There are a great many programs that you can use, so I would use what you are most comfortable with.